# How to disable Google Chrome auto-opening spotify playlist links

Tags: google-chrome, audio, spotify

When clicking play button on spotify playlist site from Google Chrome, like: http://open.spotify.com/user/barackobama/playlist/6J9kgSvipjimfDLYTsCOAv

Spotify opens and starts playing music. I have blocked site handlers from Google Chrome settings, but still the spotify starts playing the music. Why spotify overrides Google Chrome settings and how to block it?